# Not able to get a new page while scraping using POST request on .aspx site using JSOUP

Tags: asp.net, http, web-scraping, jsoup, htmlunit

I want to scrape data from from a particular site. It has some filters which need to be selected to get data. I'm trying to use JSOUP and post the form data and get the html for the new selection in filter. Below is my code. every time I try running the program I'm getting only the default pages html i.e., the page with the new filter input data is not obtained.

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://45.114.246.184/bsmm/Dashboards/DB.aspx").timeout(50*1000).get();

    Elements viewState = doc.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE");
    Elements viewStateGen = doc.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR");
    Elements eventValidation = doc.select("input[name=__EVENTVALIDATION]");

    Map<String,String> allFields = new HashMap<String,String>();
    allFields.put("ctl00$ScriptManager1", "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$updatepanel|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnfilter");
    allFields.put("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddltop", "1");
    allFields.put("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddl1", "12");
    allFields.put("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddl2", "117");
    allFields.put("__EVENTTARGET", "");
    allFields.put("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
    allFields.put("__LASTFOCUS", "");
    allFields.put("__VIEWSTATE", viewState.val());
    allFields.put("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation.val());
    allFields.put("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", viewStateGen.val());
    allFields.put("__ASYNCPOST", "true");
    allFields.put("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnfilter", "Submit");
    allFields.put("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnrefresh", "Reset");


    Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://45.114.246.184/bsmm/Dashboards/DB.aspx")
            //.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36")
            .data(allFields)
            .timeout(50*1000)
            .method(Method.POST).
            execute();

    Document doc2  = Jsoup.connect("http://45.114.246.184/bsmm/Dashboards/DB.aspx")
            .cookies(res.cookies())
            .timeout(50*1000)
            .get();

    System.out.println(doc2);
```

Am I doing something wrong is just JSOUP not the right tool in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Did you tried later as is said in message. Maybe service was unavailable for some time?

Comment: Yes, tried lot many times. Can you check the 1st method I used , error 500 is for the 2nd approach I've taken.

Comment: I have executed your code and got this result: https://justpaste.it/1jhiv

Comment: Maybe you have tried too many times, and your IP address is blocked. Can you try with another IP.

Comment: Hi Luk. The result you pasted is what I'm getting too. But thats incorrect, the data obtained there is the default page data not the after the dropdowns are selected. My problem is with not obtaining the data for selected drop downs. I'm also editing the question to remove the 500 error that I posted, It's creating some confusion for the viewer.